# Is it possible to return multiple columns using 1 case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 case statements that are exactly the same `CASE` criteria, but they all have different `THEN/ELSE` statements.

Is it possible to do this all in one, or do I need to separate these all out and copy and paste the code multiple times?

```
,CASE WHEN lm.Id IN ('1','2','3') THEN lm.name ELSE lm.Desc END AS [Column1]
,CASE WHEN lm.Id IN ('1','2','3') THEN '3' ELSE '1' END AS [Column2]
,CASE WHEN lm.Id IN ('1','2','3') THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS [Column3]
```

Is it possible to do this with less code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in strict SQL. Some DB engines may support it as an extension.  You could probably accomplish functionally the same thing through some other mechanism, though... possibly with a JOIN, or a UNION.

Comment: Sql Server will fail if you try to seperate anything in a case with a comma, so most likely he is stuck with 3 case statements

Answer (score 1):

Suggest `UNION`ing your resultsets. It won't get you fewer lines of code, but perhaps more readable.

```
SELECT [name], '3', 'True'
From Mytable WHERE ID IN ('1','2','3')
UNION 
SELECT [desc], '1', 'False'
From Mytable WHERE ID NOT IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: +1 seems like the best way to solve this specific issue, I would use UNION ALL instead for better performance

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to `update` the table using `where`? In the `select` statement of your question you can declare `Column1`, `Column2` and `Column3` as `NULL` and with two `update` statements change the values.

With "only" three columns depending on same `case` statement the code below doesn't save much typing (probably execution time..?) but it comes handy when you have more than 3...

```
UPDATE MyTable
      SET Column1 = lm.name,
          Column2 = '3',
          Column3 = 'True'
WHERE lm.Id IN ('1','2','3')

UPDATE MyTable
      SET Column1 = lm.Desc,
          Column2 = '1',
          Column3 = 'False'
WHERE lm.Id NOT IN ('1','2','3')
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give, I would not try to make any change. If your test ( WHEN ... THEN ) involved a lot more calculation, or if it was repeated a lot more often, you could consider setting up a subquery to evaluate it. But with only a small amount of repetition, why bother? The code you have is easy to read, and not expensive to execute.